# Serving changing files with Flask

Tags: python, linux, flask

I currently am using Flask to serve up a visual programming environment. I would like the users to be able to load the code currently in the system if they come back later. I have tried using:

```
return redirect(url_for('static', filename='rawxml.txt'))
return redirect(send_from_directory('static', 'rawxml.txt'))
```

However, both will never serve the modified version of the file, and instead what seems to be a cached version of the file. How can I serve a file that gets rewritten often with the new content.

Note: rawxml.txt is stored in the "static" directory, but it is a sym link to where the actual XML is (I have tried a hard link as well).

Comment: I guess you can set HTTP headers to avoid caching, but in your case it could be best to save files with special names, like for example `e51564ccd047b3cb5e27ef66c036c574.txt` where the name is the corresponding MD5 hash of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
url = url_for('static', filename='rawxml.txt', t=time.time())
return redirect(url)
```

If the content is not that dynamic, you can rewrite it to use an MD5 hash of the file - this way you will only invalidate the cache when the file changes. The answer from [tbicr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880326/tbicr) looks like a good example of this.

[update]

At the jQuery side, do something like:

```
$('#some_selector').load('{{ url }}#'+new Date().valueOf());
```

Comment: Just FYI, `url_for` adds keyword arguments that aren't params to the query string - so you can simplify it to: `url_for('static', filename='rawxml.txt', t=time.time())`

Comment: This works well on the Flask side, however on the Javascript side I am having what I believe is a caching issue. I load the file via a JQuery get request, and in Chrome it stops making a GET request to the Flask server after a few times. It works flawlessly in Firefox. Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I have next implementation for static files:

```
hash_cache = {}

@app.url_defaults
def add_hash_for_static_files(endpoint, values):
    '''Add content hash argument for url to make url unique.
    It's have sense for updates to avoid caches.
    '''
    if endpoint != 'static':
        return
    filename = values['filename']
    if filename in hash_cache:
        values['hash'] = hash_cache[filename]
        return
    filepath = safe_join(app.static_folder, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as static_file:
            filehash = get_hash(static_file.read(), 8)
            values['hash'] = hash_cache[filename] = filehash
```

It just add hash argument to urls which generated with `url_for`.

Comment: would you mind sharing the definition of `get_hash`? I'd be happy to edit the response and add the missing imports as well (`os` and `safe_join` from flask). thanks!

Comment: @GregSadetsky, something like `get_hash = lambda content, length: hashlib.md5(content).hexdigest()[:length]`